# In azure load test tool, single iteration script is not working

Tags: performance, loops, jmeter, load-testing, azure-load-testing

I am using Azure load testing tool and uploaded my jmeter script into it. Jmeter script is containing single user and single iteration. I need to run test for 1 user and 1 iteration only. But in azure load testing test is not running for single iteration, its running out of time in multiple iterations continuously. If instead of loop count i mention the test duration then test runs exactly for same duration. But loop count of 1 is not working and I need to run test for just one iteration.